# screen command to persistently enable menu at bottom

Tags: linux, menu, gnu-screen

I am using the Linux Screen Utility to open more than 2 windows in my Putty terminal. Usually while running a screen session a

```
Ctrl+A Ctrl+W
```

gives us a list of window at the bottom of the screen.

I have two questions:

- I wanted to know if there is a way to persistently keep this menu at the bottom of the screen.
- How to give name to each window? Ideally when we execute

  screen -S screen_name

the screen_name should appear in the menu. I can only find

`0.csh 1.csh 2.csh`

in the menu. can this be changed to

```
0.debug_screen 1.editor 2.games
```

Comment: You can name windows on the fly by typing `C-a` `A`.

Comment: Isn't C-a A used for altering between two screens? could you please elaborate.

Comment: `C-a` `C-a` is used for altering between windows.  And `C-a` `a` is used for passing a `C-a` to the program running in the screen (a shell typically).  You need precision in distinguishing the three: `C-a` `A` for setting a window's title is with a capital A (`S-a`).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have following lines in my `.screenrc` (found in [Short Tip: GNU Screen with proper scroll, session management support](http://liquidat.wordpress.com/2008/10/17/short-tip-gnu-screen-with-proper-scroll-session-management-support/)):

```
caption always # activates window caption
caption string '%{= wk}[ %{k}%H %{k}][%= %{= wk}%?%-Lw%?%{r}(%{r}%n*%f%t%?(%u)%?%{r})%{k}%?%+Lw%?%?%= %{k}][%{b} %Y-%m-%d %{k}%c %{k}]'
```

A description of those cryptic identifiers can be found in the [screen manpage](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html), section [*STRING ESCAPES*](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#String-Escapes).

Btw.: Instead of `caption` you can also use `hardstatus` (which is displayed only once at the bottom line if you use split screens).

Windows can be renamed using `C-a` `A` (see again [screen manpage](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html), section [*Commands*](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Commands)).

Answer (score 1):

I have the following line in my .screenrc which gives me a caption line at the bottom of the screen:

```
screen $SHELL -c 'screen -X caption always "%{= RW} $STY | %c:%s `date +%Z` | host:%H | load:%l | escape:CTRL-U "'
```

This gives me the following:

```
%{= RW}         <== White text on red background
$STY            <== Name of the screen session e.g. "4169.debug_screen"
%c:%s           <== The time in 24 hour format with seconds
`date +%Z`      <== The timezone the server is configured to
host:%H         <== The hostname of the server
load:%l         <== The current load averages of the server
escape:CTRL-U   <== A textual reminder that the screen escape key is set to CTRL-U (not CTRL-A)
```

I use different colour backgrounds on different machines so I remember if I'm on a production or development server - red for production to remind me to be even more careful than usual.

To get the list of screens running including names I just type 'screen -ls' (which I've aliased to 'scls').